# What does the * mean when in a C++ method signature?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I know enough that a `*` relates to a pointer. I'm still trying to sort that out in my head (pointers versus references.)

I'm working through a C++ book and there is a method signature in it like this:

```
void DrawBitmap(char *filename, int x, int y)
```

What does the `*` mean in this situation? is it accepting a pointer, or a reference to a variable?

Thanks for any help... and for putting up with an admittedly noob question.

Comment: It expects an _array_ of `char`-s (the C way of representing a string). The array is passed as a pointer to the first element.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin In fact it is a pointer rather than an array

Comment: You need to go back to the book really

Comment: If you have a **C++** book teaching you to do things like that, then you might be learning from a very outdated book.  It looks as if it's trying to teach you the C language first (That used to be the done thing back in the 1990s, but not in 2012).  C++ includes a `string` type for handling strings - passing _char*_ to a function is a very outdated way of doing things.

Comment: the book is Beginner Game Programming with C++. I'm actually a bit disappointed with it because it doesn't really explain C++ that much. At one point, the author even says that instead of explaing pointers he rather that readers of his book just use them and we'll get it eventually.

Comment: Time to get a better book. Don't worry about game programming. Learn to program, and then think about game specific techniques. For books, refer to this excellent Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: I've been professionally programming C# for a couple years now. My programming knowledge so far has been higher level to this point. I want to get in games programming as a hobby and I would LOVE to learn a foundational language like C++. Thanks for the link too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that you're passing it a pointer to a character, which usually means that pointer points to the first character in an array of characters. With a pointer (`*`), you can do arithmetic, e.g. (fileName + 1) to get the second character. When you use a reference (`&`), you are implying that the receiving function should operate on the original data. Without the reference, the function is passed a copy, rather than the original.

Comment: Very succinct. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: "When you use a reference (&), you are implying" -- very poor choice of words. You're not 'implying' anything.

Comment: Please provide a better choice of words, then, and tell me how it offers no implication.

Answer (score 1):

Others have directly answered your question already; some of the following links are well worth a read for information about pointers (and their *syntactical* relationship to arrays in C++), they're well worth studying and I would recommend taking a little time reading through them to get your head around the ideas:

http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/

http://www.augustcouncil.com/~tgibson/tutorial/ptr.html

http://www.augustcouncil.com/~tgibson/tutorial/arr.html

http://www.eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/languages/jsw_tut_pointers.aspx

http://www.daweidesigns.com/cgi-bin/pointers.php

Answer (score 0):

`char *filename` is pointer to a character you are passing to `DrawBitmap` method. For more details please [see this link](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/krnotes/sx8e.html).